# Xcode iOS remove framework's permission request

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, info.plist

I developed a game for iOS using Unity. I use a lot of frameworks and libraries (especially for serving ads). But my app is always requesting a location permission: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`. I don't even know which framework needs this permission but I want to disable this requests. Is there a possibility to do that without removing a framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside Xcode, Go to your info.plist file. there should be a permission mentioned there.

"Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description"

Click on it and then click "-". Like this

[image]

It will remove the permission asked on runtime but if it's required because of any framework attached then it may cause some issues.

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks! I removed this from info.plist and there is no request anymore. What issues can occur?

Comment: Some frameworks may require location in order to improve their performance, Example: Navigation. If the permission is not there then it may not perform as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for explanations!